# Insert two elements in $push with a $cond in Mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, push

I have this query in `mongodb`, which represent the won team will have 3 points and the draw teams will have 1 each.

```
db.football.aggregate([ 
  { "$match": {
      "$and": [
        { "Div": "SP1" }
      ]
    }
  },
  { "$group": { 
      "_id": {
        "div": "$Div"
      },
      "teams": { 
        "$push": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$FTR", "H" ] }, 
            "then": { "T": "$HomeTeam", "P": 3 },
            "else": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": [ "$FTR", "A" ] }, 
                "then": { "T": "$AwayTeam", "P": 3 },
                "else": {
                  "$cond": {
                    "if": { "$eq": [ "$FTR", "D" ] }, 
                    "then": { "draws": [{ "T": "$HomeTeam", "P": 1}, { "T": "$AwayTeam", "P": 1 }] },
                    "else": "Error" 
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which result in:

```
{ "_id" : { "div" : "SP1" }, 
          "teams" : [ 
                      { "T" : "La Coruna", "P" : 3 },
                      { "T" : "Malaga", "P" : 3 },
                      { "draws": [
                                   { "T" : "Barcelona", "P" : 1 },
                                   { "T" : "Villarreal", "P" : 1 }
                                 ]
                      },
                     ...
                    ]
}
```

See that I have an array for the draws teams, but I just want a big array in teams as the below:

```
{ "_id" : { "div" : "SP1" }, 
          "teams" : [ 
                      { "T" : "La Coruna", "P" : 3 },
                      { "T" : "Malaga", "P" : 3 },
                      { "T" : "Barcelona", "P" : 1 },
                      { "T" : "Villarreal", "P" : 1 },
                     ...
                    ]
}
```

I have tried to `unwind` teams field but wasn't effective.

The dataset can be download here: https://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1617/SP1.csv
The information of the dataset: https://www.football-data.co.uk/notes.txt

To import the csv:

```
mongoimport -d dataset -c football --type csv --file path_to_file_SP1.csv --headerline --drop --stopOnError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to flatten your array. Since you have two different kinds of elements you can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) with [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) to determine whether you should combine single element or `draws` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            teams: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$teams",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: [ { $type: "$$this.draws" }, "array" ] },
                            { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this.draws" ] },
                            { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", ["$$this"] ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B_JxqvXq-W2)